# Google App Engine(Flexible Environment)--In Php 8.2 -When Include JQuery,CSS, image,but not affect in my application

Tags: google-app-engine, php8.1

I deployed my application in GAE Flexible Environment PHP 8.2 as per Google document.My deployment Finished Successfully, In my Application I included  Jquery(https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js), CSS, Images, That and all not affected   Using Php 8.2(Flexible Environment).

My App.yaml

runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:

operating_system: "ubuntu22"
document_root: .

My index.php

`
<!doctype html>

$(document).ready(function(){

  alert('inside');



 })

## Welcome

`

Output Php 8.2(image breaking):
[document ready not working,CSS not affect,image breaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz7fP.png)

My expected output is(This one php 7.2 GAE(Flexible Environment)
[with image and CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqpXv.png)

I need help to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did anyone know the solution for my problem

Comment: I got one suggestion from google community , in that they said update NGINX config file for above said issue.What my question is ,is there any security issue will come, if we update that config file.I need to know that one.

Comment: Then How to download our GAE PROJECT NGINX config file. Can anyone know about that.

Comment: Did anyone know solution for my  issue